# Spring Boot SSL Configured, Server up but not able to connect to Port

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

I have tried boot application with recent version,wanted to make the rest api ssl secured, I have done below
Created the keystore and put into project classpath, the server got  started , no problem with starting,but not able to send request 8080 or 8443, below are the configuration,

> server.ssl.key-store=KeyStore.p12
>   server.ssl.key-store-password=shashank server.ssl.key-alias=mydomain
>   server.ssl.key-password=shashank
>
> ```
> @Bean
>    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
>       TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
>    @Override
>    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
>    SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
>    securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
>    SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
>    collection.addPattern("/*");
>    securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
>    context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
>    }
>    };
>    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
>    return tomcat;
>    }
>
>   private Connector getHttpConnector() {
>         Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
>         connector.setScheme("https");
>         connector.setPort(8080);
>         connector.setSecure(true);
>         connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
>
> }
> ```
>
> INFO 84898 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnskJ.png)
>   8443 (https) 8080 (https) with context path '/event-processing'

as this is self signed certificate, it says " this certificate is not verfied from third party"

The intention is here is to make https to all rest api's
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnskJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try out these changes :

Modify `application.properties` to edit `server.ssl.key-store` parameter value to `keystore.p12` from `KeyStore.p12`

```
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
```

Add the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean to  @Configuration class (any one).

```
 @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
          SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
          securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
          SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
          collection.addPattern("/*");
          securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
          context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
      };

    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
  }

  private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

    return connector;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with a self signed certificate and solved it by making the certificate in the server machine instead of in my local machine , so you should run the keytool command that makes the certificate in the server machine and use that .p12 generated file in your project and every thing will work as expected.